# Ubuntu, fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory #include <Python.h>

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I try to install psycopg2 the error appears

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      #include <Python.h>
```

Because, there is a search for this file along the path `/usr/include/python3.8`

But this file is located in the path `/usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.x`

How to solve this problem?? Is Python installed in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear what version of Ubuntu you are using. Assuming it is a fresh install and you don't have these installed. I would suggest you install the following

`sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev build-essential`

Once these are installed then try again installing `psycopg2`

Comment: I have it, the problem is not in it, I indicated that Python.h is there, but psycopg2 looks for it in a different directory. Version 18.04

Comment: are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Yes i do use it

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/1038)